# Unity instantiating prefabs one by one or in chunks?(performance question)

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d android platformer and I have some performance issues. My question is how should I instanciate the objects? One by one right before they appear on screen or 10-20 of them in a chunk all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targetting mobile devices then it is a bad idea to instantiate numbers of prefabs. What you can do is use object pooling like simply activate and deactivate prefabs.

Answer (score 0):

if you are already having performance issues than one by one is the way to go, chunking can work well, and as long as your destroying you platforms when they leave the screen its not a problem, but if you have the ability to go back to previous platforms your going to slow down more with the more you add. so if you are side scrolling, chunking is not a bad idea, specifically if you will have variable speeds, having a few platforms ready will prevent your new platform appearing mid-screen at higher player speeds.